# Manually installed connectors are not loded by kafka connect 7.1.1

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to customise kafka connect docker image 7.1.1 with new manually installed connectors.
The connectors are packaged as uber jar and I'm adding them to the plugin path.

When starting the container the new added connectors are not loaded (doesn’t figure in the response from: http://localhost:8083/connector-plugins)

I have followed the steps described [here](https://docs.confluent.io/home/connect/self-managed/extending.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the new jars, I had to make sure to change the files owner to `appuser:appuser`